# How to enable button do verify in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one button section product, but it disables when hover mouse on section product then the button is enabled. I don't know write script do enable a button when Selenium WebDriver finds it.

```
@Test(priority = 4)
public void TestSelectedItem() {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/product-list/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a")).click();
    Select drpItem = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pa_colors")));
    drpItem.selectByIndex(2);
    driver.findElement(By.className("add_to_cart_button")).click();

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML`? Are you seeing any error? Update the question with the error stack trace please.

Comment: do the same thing you are doing manually. search for how to do mousehoever even in selenium

Comment: please access url: http://webshop-2.demo.devinition.com/, in site, when hover mouse on item, button is display. How to use Selenium Webdriver find button when button is disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you code in Python which do hover action on the element:

```
hover_company = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your XPath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", hover_company)
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hover_company)
hover.perform()
```

First two lines scroll to your element, last two lines -- do hover action on the element.
After this action -- you can click on the button. Try on.

Code in Java:

```
hover_company = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your XPath"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", hover_company);
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
hover.moveToElement(hover_company).perform();
```